# jQuery date-picker glyphicon icon missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

for this past few days, I came across a very **strange & odd**. I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate my field, named **"start date"**. This field has a simple validation method where the *required* is set to **true**. I was able to successfully validate the field. However, I received a strange problem. When the field is validated to **either** valid or invalid, the **glyphicon-calendar** **icon** will magically **disappear**. I tried to troubleshoot by looking at the inspector tool, turns out this code which is the calender icon was **completely removed** once validated.

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

I've spend a few hours researching but no one seems to receive this odd problem. Does anyone know why? **Help is greatly needed!** Here is a screenshot of my problem and my current codes

[image: glyphicon-calender icon **missing** when field is **valid**]

[image: glyphicon-calender icon **missing** when field is **invalid**]

[image: glyphicon-calender span element **missing** by looking at **inspector tool**]

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                if (element.type === "radio") {
                    this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                } else {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                if (element.type === "radio") {
                    this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                } else {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
                }
            }
        });

        $('#dataForm').validate({
            rules: {
                startDateInput: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="#">
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="startDateInput">Start Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="startDateInput" style="max-width: 280px" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDateInput">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/gud7xjy0/10/

Comment: It's not missing, it's appearing on the right of the screen instead of where you're expecting it to be

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan I am talking about the calender icon, you can take a look at the screenshot that I've provided or the jsFiddle

Comment: Is it because you are removing it? `$(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();`

Comment: Well that's because you're removing it...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi Rory, I completely mislooked that, I am truly sorry I am new to this. However, do you know why the glyphicon-Ok icon and glyphicon-remove icon are appearing at the side of the screen rather than in the textbox?

Comment: @Rich I am so sorry, I completely mislooked that.

Comment: @Rich However, do you know why the glyphicon-Ok icon and glyphicon-remove icon are appearing at the side of the screen rather than in the textbox?

Comment: Code Snippet is broken and pointless if you don't include the plugins.  Please don't use the Code Snippet feature if you're not going to use it correctly.  Otherwise, providing a jsFiddle instead of Code Snippet is fine.

Comment: @Sparky Ok, sorry my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Rich in the comments, the following line removes the icon.

```
$(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();
```